# How to recognizie number of people from photo taken from above?

Tags: image-processing, azure-cognitive-services, azure-machine-learning-service

I have 3 person sofa in room. I have camera storing images to Azure Blob storage.

I have tested that Azure Cognitive Services Emotion API can count number of faces if camera is located in front of user. It can count that 1,2 or 2 person is sitting. I'm using blog triggered Azure functions to process data to Emotion API.

I realize now that camera must be installed to roof because of physical requirement of room. Roof is only place where camera can be mounted.

Emotion API cannot be used since camera from above cannot see faces. Camera sees top of head.

1) Do you know any methods for counting number of people from above?

2) Do you know if I'm able to determine which position is used. Let say that person sits in left side and middle and right side is unused.

Comment: this can be solved using simple image processing techniques. a machine learning approach would be complete overkill in my opinion

Comment: Please let me know sample or tutorial compatible to Azure